# postgresql: Why do I have to specify -h localhost when running psql?

Tags: macos, postgresql

`psql mydb` yields:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

`psql -h localhost mydb` works just fine. `pg_hba.conf` looks like:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

What up?

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same thing happen to me, presumably due to the conflicting version of psql (one from Lion, one from homebrew). While I still haven't been able to figure out how to make psql use the /tmp socket directory, I do have a work around.

Put the following in your .bashrc (or .zshrc, etc):

```
export PGHOST=/tmp
```

This sets the correct "host" back to the correct socket directory, without having to supply the -h flag

Answer (score 6):

Probably psql and the server use a different location for the unix-domain socket.
( /var/pgsql_socket/ is a strange location) This can happen if you are mixing binaries from different packages. 
Try to locate the socket ( /tmp/ is a good place to start) You can force psql to use a different directory by misusing the -h option:

```
psql -h /tmp/
```

Comment: +1 for `-h` switch, which works as well for local connections (forward slash at beginning). Unix-domain socket's path is determined by [`unix_socket_directory`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-UNIX-SOCKET-DIRECTORY) property in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: The 'unix_socket_directory' property can be empty (I've never seen it set), in which case it presumably defaults to /tmp/.

Comment: Thanks for the tip- I'm using the standard OS X packages from postgres, which explains the unix-domain socket setting.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a [reported defect](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30125).

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on OS X, and the problem was that `/usr/bin/psql` is what I was using, but postmaster was running from `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0`. Using `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/psql` (getting that into my `PATH` before all else) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers addressed other alternatives, I guess I could provide something about *Mac OS X Server* on Lion. I run into very similar issue - in my case even `-h localhost` didn't work as networking was disabled in PostregSQL which is by the way in many cases very good idea. The thing with Mac OS X Server is that it launches PostgreSQL server via `launchd`.

Some hints as you go around:

- `serveradmin` service: `postgres`
- `launchd` configuration file: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`
- database folder: `/var/pgsql`
- socket folder: `/var/pgsql_socket`

That configuration file overrides several configuration directives that can be found in `postgresql.conf` under database folder. Especially these two:

- `unix_socket_group`
- `unix_socket_permissions`

You can find that `_postgres` account is used to run the server and everything is also accessible if active user is member of `_postgres` group.

By running `dscl . -read /Groups/_postgres GroupMembership` you can see that by default that group has these members: `_devicemgr` `_calendar` `_teamsserver` `_www`

I guess you have two options. Add yourself to _postgres group or change `launchd` configuration plist file. The later is just plain text editing... But beware of security, because this way you'll be opening Server to whatever meets criteria you change (see the last paragraph).

The former can be done either via `Server.app` or via `dscl` command-line utility. The first option probably doesn't need anything to be added. Just make sure that you can see System Accounts (View -> Hide/Show System Accounts). I'm kind of CLI junkie so this should add your user to `_postgres` group:

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/_postgres GroupMembership $USER
```

Of course you should be careful what you run under your account then because you're giving access to you Mac OS X Server database back-end. So either secure you `_postgres` account or create separate user to manipulate your database or don't save anything private there.