# psql could not connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql

I am currently working on a ruby on rails application and I am having problems running a RSpec test. With further drilling , i went into my terminal and tried to run the simple psql command

psql

This message cam back immediately:
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

What is weird is when i go into my localhost: I can clearly see the database information(i.e. customer information and what not).  Is there something I can do to remedy this situation?

Thanks for any help with this matter

Comment: Please search Google for the error message you got. You will immediately find lots of information about PostgreSQL, Mac OS X, and unix socket issues. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032585/postgresql-mountain-lion-socket-issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369164/postgresql-why-do-i-have-to-specify-h-localhost-when-running-psql,

Answer (score 1):

[The Easy Way to Get Started With PostgreSQL on a Mac](http://chris-schmitz.com/the-easy-way-to-get-started-with-postgresql-on-a-mac-postgres-dot-app-and-induction/) it helped me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this on the command line
    $export PGHOST=localhost